# Would stripe know if a payment method is valid?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments, backend

My app requires a user to enter their payment method, which they may use for purchases in the future.

At the point of accepting the payment method:

1. Is it possible for stripe to know whether or not the payment method is valid and how much it can be charged?

As time passes, will stripe be able to know if the payment method has expired or know how much it can be charge as this values changes over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, stripe knows the payment method validation. If it's not valid or expires stripe throws an error and you can catch it on your side and perform accordingly. If the purchase method expires stripes throws an error and retries at most 5 times (I guess, I forgot the exact number).

And the dynamicity, stripe charges the amount you want it to charge. You set the chargeable amount and stripe does its work.

Comment: What about enough funds? Does the stripe know whether or not the payment method has sufficient funds for the the amount reqested?

Comment: This will be handled by the payment merchants. If there are not enough funds then the stripe gets an error and the payment gets canceled.

Comment: Are there any penalties for failed transactions due to insufficient funds?

Comment: I'm not sure, you need to read stripe docs for that